# How can I read yaml (Configuration) file as JSON in dropwizard?

Tags: java, json, ruby, yaml, dropwizard

I want to parse configuration yaml file as a JSON Object in Dropwizard.
As in Python and Ruby we can directly read yaml file as JSON:

```
require 'yaml'
conf = YAML.load_file('some.yml')
puts conf.<some key>
```

I want to follow the same protocol and do not want to make a separate class to map the yaml structure, but not sure how to achieve it in Java.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, instead of defining a class to represent the structure of you JSON or YAML, you want to retrieve an object that gives you access to the JSON object in a generic manner.

Even though this is a bit contrary to the way dropwizard wants to do things (i.e., having typed class to access configuration data), it is relatively easy:

1. You need an instance of Jackson `ObjectMapper`: the one provided by dropwizard or you own, YAML-aware (see example below).
2. You can call the `readTree` method to transform an input into a `JsonNode` which gives you access to the JSON/YAML object in memory.

See [`ObjectMapper#readTree`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(byte[])) and similar methods.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(new File("some.yml"));
System.out.println(json.get("test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [Configuration](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/core.html#id4) object from DropWizard, either the default or a custom one that has been created to hold additional parameters. This object is available on the [Application](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/core.html#application) class, under the "run" method in particular. Using the DW configuration example:

```
public class ExampleConfiguration extends Configuration {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private MessageQueueFactory messageQueue = new MessageQueueFactory();

    @JsonProperty("messageQueue")
    public MessageQueueFactory getMessageQueueFactory() {
        return messageQueue;
    }

    @JsonProperty("messageQueue")
    public void setMessageQueueFactory(MessageQueueFactory factory) {
        this.messageQueue = factory;
    }
}
```

You can get/set all the attributes from YAML file as below:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application<ExampleConfiguration> {

    ...

    public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {

        configuration.getMessageQueueFactory();
        configuration.getServerFactory();
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole point is to not add getter/setter. This is the actual way how its done in dropwizard.

Comment: I misunderstood the question @divyum. Maybe you can just parse the YAML file to a HashMap and retrieve the attributes using string keys? You would still need a new Jackson mapper...

Comment: Indeed that is the way @André Barbosa, but have to remove Jackson mapper from the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson can both parse yaml and format to JSON.
See an example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson).

Comment: The whole point is not to create a separate schema/mapper to read yaml, but the link you provided does not do it.